# Open form in UI thread from 2ndary thread

Tags: .net, winforms, multithreading

I have a .Net40/Winforms app that runs an script in a worker thread.  The script needs to create a secondary form in the UI thread because the form shouldn't terminate with the script.  In Win32, I use PostMessage(mainWnd...).  What's the accepted way to do this in .Net?

Max

Comment: Can you clarify "because the form shouldn't terminate with the script" please ?

Comment: If I create the form directly in the script's thread, the form disappears when the script and it's thread is terminated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the worker thread, you should use the "Invoke" method of any control to execute some code in the UI Thread.

Control.Invoke from MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: This is correct. Control.Invoke is the same as PostMessage in Windows API.